# Extending a class with property as another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, properties

Iv'e been working with inheritance now a little bit and i found myself writing most of the code in the constructor section of the classes, and I got to the point where theres so many attributes that it's a lot easier to categorize them, I did it by declaring an empty object class and created inside the main class a property that returns the object class as a category of data:

```
import somemodule as sm


class Background(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class Border(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class Main(sm.SomeClass):
    def __init__(self, item):
        super().__init__(self)

        self.item = item

        # some more attribute from the parent class
        # starts getting messy

        self.bd.width = 10
        self.bd.color = 'blue'
                                    # looks cleaner than self.bg_color
        self.bg.accent = 'yellow'
        self.bg.color = 'green'
        

    @property
    def bg(self)
        return Background

    @bg.getter
    def bg(self)
        return Background

    @property
    def bd(self)
        return Border

    @bd.getter
    def bd(self)
        return Border


ins = Main('app')
```

I'm just getting used to classes and I don't yet understand very well how to make use of `@decorator`s.

My question is whether it's "pythonic" in any way or perhaps even entirely incorrect and what is the correct way?

Comment: Its not clear here what exactly you are trying to accomplish or what your exact problem is. Are you saying you want to encapsulate attributes into classes so it is easier to manage in the constructor? Returning class types does not do this and `@decorators` are something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is using class `composition`

In OOP when looking at `inheritance` vs `composition`

Inheritance models an **IS A** relationship and composition models a **HAS A** relationship

i.e.

```
class Border: # omit
class Background # omit

# main HAS A Background and Border and IS A sm.SomeClass
class Main(sm.SomeClass):
    Background bg
    Border bd
```

Give this article a read: https://realpython.com/inheritance-composition-python/

Also, in python 3 I don't believe you need to extend/inherit from the `object` class.